# CUDA and C++ link/compilation, program crashes on cudaMalloc

Tags: c++, memory, cuda

I have two problems I would like to present to you.

I)

I have a `.cpp` file where is the `main()` and in order to call the kernel (in the .`cu` file), I use the `extern` function to the `.cu` file, `launch()`, which calls the kernel. The two files, the `.cu` and `.cpp` separately are being compiled successfully. So as to bind them together, since I am a beginner in `CUDA`, I tried two things:

1) `nvcc -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -o final file1.cpp file2.cu`, which gives no errors and compiles the final program successfully and

2)

```
nvcc -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -c file2.cu
   g++ -c file1.cpp
   g++ -o program file1.o file2.o -lcudart -lcurand -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda
```

In the second case, since the `-l` parameters are not recognized (only `-lcuda` is), I guess because I didn't specify their paths since I don't know where these files are stored. If I skip these `-l` parameters, the error is:

```
$ g++ -o final backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.o backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.o -lcuda
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.o: In function `launch':
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `cudaConfigureCall'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.o: In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x259): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.o: In function `__nv_init_managed_rt_with_module(void**)':
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x274): undefined reference to `__cudaInitModule'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.o: In function `__device_stub__Z21neural_network_kernelPfPiS0_PdS1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_S1_(float*, int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*)':
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2ac): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2cf): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2f2): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x315): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x338): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.o:tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x35b): more undefined references to `cudaSetupArgument' follow
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.o: In function `__nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback(void**)':
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x663): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFunction'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_69_tmpxft_0000717b_00000000_7_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy_cpp1_ii_43082cd7()':
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x67c): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.o: In function `cudaError cudaLaunch<char>(char*)':
tmpxft_0000717b_00000000-4_backpropalgorithm_CUDA_kernel_copy.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x6c0): undefined reference to `cudaLaunch'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.o: In function `main':
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x194): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x1b4): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x1c8): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x21f): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x236): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x256): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x26a): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x28a): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x2a1): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x2c1): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x2d5): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x2f5): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x309): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x329): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x33d): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x35d): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x371): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x391): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x3a5): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x3c5): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x3dc): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x3fc): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x413): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x433): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x44a): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x46a): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x481): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x4a1): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
backpropalgorithm_CUDA_main_copy.cpp:(.text+0x5bf): undefined reference to `cudaDeviceSynchronize'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The thing is, that in the first case with the "successful" compilation and link, when I run the program it shows as output only a blinking cursor (at next line from the input command) and nothing else, in the console; normally it should calculate and show the errors of the neural network that is being constructed, using `CUDA`.

II) 
I'm trying to `printf()` in the `.cu` file but it does not show anything. I searched about it and found out that probably I should use the `cuPrintf()` function. I tried, but I had issues with the headers, the include files they were not defined, even though I included them manually. I found that I should include a cuPrintf.cu file, which source code I found online.

Unfortunately, then, when I compiled them separately, the error for the `.cu` file was

```
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_Z8cuPrintfIjEiPKcT_'
```

and the `.cpp` had no errors, though.

Why are all these errors occurring? Where is the wrong part? Why the program does not run properly and `printf()` seems not to be working in the kernel? Why does the program show only a blinking cursor and nothing more?
I would be extremely grateful if someone can enlighten me about any of these problems, thank you very much in advance!

My code for the two files are:

`file1.cpp` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include "/home/user/include_files/cuda-8.0/include/cuda.h"
#include "/home/user/include_files/cuda-8.0/include/cuda_runtime.h"
#include "/home/user/include_files/cuda-8.0/include/cuda_runtime_api.h"

#define datanum 4       // number of training samples
#define InputN 16       // number of neurons in the input layer
#define hn 64           // number of neurons in the hidden layer
#define OutN 1          // number of neurons in the output layer
#define threads_per_block 256




   using namespace std;

extern "C"
void launch(float *randData, int *times, int *loop, double *error, double *max, double *min, double *x_out, double *hn_out, double *y_out, double *y, double *w, double *v, double *deltaw, double *deltav, double *hn_delta, double *y_delta, double *alpha, double *beta, double *sumtemp, double *errtemp);

__global__ void neural_network_kernel (float *randData, int *times, int *loop, double *error, double *max, double *min, double *x_out, double *hn_out, double *y_out, double *y, double *w, double *v, double *deltaw, double *deltav, double *hn_delta, double *y_delta, double *alpha, double *beta, double *sumtemp, double *errtemp);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("welcome1\n");   
    int times = 100000;

    double sigmoid(double);
    //string result = "";
    char buffer[200];
printf("welcome2\n");
    double x_out[InputN];       // input layer
printf("welcome3\n");
    double hn_out[hn];          // hidden layer
printf("welcome4\n");
    double y_out[OutN];         // output layer
printf("welcome5\n");
    double y[OutN];             // expected output layer
printf("welcome6\n");
    double w[InputN][hn];       // weights from input layer to hidden layer
    double v[hn][OutN];         // weights from hidden layer to output layer

    double deltaw[InputN][hn];
    double deltav[hn][OutN];
printf("welcome7\n");
    double hn_delta[hn];        // delta of hidden layer
    double y_delta[OutN];       // delta of output layer
    //double errlimit = 0.001;
    double alpha = 0.1, beta = 0.1;
    int i, j, m;
    double sumtemp;
    double errtemp;


    /*cudaPrintfInit();
    cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout, true);
    cudaPrintfEnd();*/

    printf("Line : main\n");

    // Training


    /*struct{
        double input[InputN];
        double teach[OutN];
    }data[datanum];

    for(m=0; m<datanum; m++){
        for(i=0; i<InputN; i++)
            data[m].input[i] = (double)rand()/32767.0;
        for(i=0;i<OutN;i++)
            data[m].teach[i] = (double)rand()/32767.0;
    }

    // Initialization
    for(i=0; i<InputN; i++){
        for(j=0; j<hn; j++){
            w[i][j] = ((double)rand()/32767.0)*2-1;
            deltaw[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<hn; i++){
        for(j=0; j<OutN; j++){
            v[i][j] = ((double)rand()/32767.0)*2-1;
            deltav[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }*/


    //curandGenerator_t gen;
    srand (time(NULL));
    float randData[threads_per_block];
printf("welcome8\n");
    for (int i=0; i<threads_per_block; i++)
    {
        randData[i] = rand()%100;   //Else, without %100, it returns some billions for number!
    }
printf("welcome9\n");
    /*curandCreateGenerator(&gen, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);
    curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen, 1234ULL);
    curandGenerateUniform(gen, randData, threads_per_block);*/
    int loop = 0;
    double error;
    double max, min;
    double *max_p_GPU, *min_p_GPU, *error_p_GPU;
    float *randData_p_GPU;
    int *times_p_GPU, *loop_p_GPU, *InputN_p_GPU, *hn_p_GPU, *OutN_p_GPU;
    double *x_out_p_GPU, *hn_out_p_GPU, *y_out_p_GPU, *y_p_GPU, *w_p_GPU, *v_p_GPU, *deltaw_p_GPU, *deltav_p_GPU, *hn_delta_p_GPU;
    double *y_delta_p_GPU, *alpha_p_GPU, *beta_p_GPU, *sumtemp_p_GPU, *errtemp_p_GPU;
    //int blocks = times/threads_per_block;

printf("welcome10\n");  
    cudaMalloc((void **)&randData_p_GPU, threads_per_block*sizeof(float));
printf("DEBUG1\n");
    cudaMemcpy(randData_p_GPU, randData, threads_per_block*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome11\n");
    cudaMalloc((void **)&times_p_GPU, sizeof(int));
printf("welcome12\n");
    cudaMemcpy(times_p_GPU, &times, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome13\n");
    cudaMalloc((void **)&loop_p_GPU, sizeof(int));
printf("welcome14\n");
    cudaMemcpy(loop_p_GPU, &loop, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome15\n");
    cudaMalloc((void **)&error_p_GPU, sizeof(double));
printf("welcome16\n");
    cudaMemcpy(error_p_GPU, &error, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome17\n");
    cudaMalloc((void **)&max_p_GPU, sizeof(double));
printf("welcome18\n");
    cudaMemcpy(max_p_GPU, &max, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome19\n");
    cudaMalloc((void **)&min_p_GPU, sizeof(double));
printf("welcome20\n");
    cudaMemcpy(min_p_GPU, &min, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome21\n");
    /* cudaMalloc((void **)&InputN_p_GPU, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(InputN_p_GPU, &InputN, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&hn_p_GPU, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(hn_p_GPU, &hn, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&OutN_p_GPU, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(OutN_p_GPU, &OutN, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); */

    /*cudaMalloc((void **)&x_out_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*(threads_per_block*InputN));
    cudaMemcpy(x_out_p_GPU, &x_out, sizeof(double)*InputN, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&hn_out_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*(threads_per_block*hn));
    cudaMemcpy(hn_out_p_GPU, &hn_out, sizeof(double)*hn, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&y_out_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*(threads_per_block*OutN));
    cudaMemcpy(y_out_p_GPU, &y_out, sizeof(double)*OutN, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&hn_delta_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*(threads_per_block*hn));
    cudaMemcpy(hn_delta_p_GPU, &hn_delta, sizeof(double)*hn, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&y_delta_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*(threads_per_block*OutN));
    cudaMemcpy(y_delta_p_GPU, &y_delta, sizeof(double)*OutN, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);*/

    cudaMalloc((void **)&x_out_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*InputN);
printf("welcome22\n");
    cudaMemcpy(x_out_p_GPU, &x_out, sizeof(double)*InputN, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome23\n");
    cudaMalloc((void **)&hn_out_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*hn);
printf("welcome24\n");
    cudaMemcpy(hn_out_p_GPU, &hn_out, sizeof(double)*hn, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome25\n");
    cudaMalloc((void **)&y_out_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*OutN);
printf("welcome26\n");
    cudaMemcpy(y_out_p_GPU, &y_out, sizeof(double)*OutN, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome27\n");
    cudaMalloc((void **)&hn_delta_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*hn);
printf("welcome28\n");
    cudaMemcpy(hn_delta_p_GPU, &hn_delta, sizeof(double)*hn, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome29\n");
    cudaMalloc((void **)&y_delta_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*OutN);
printf("welcome30\n");
    cudaMemcpy(y_delta_p_GPU, &y_delta, sizeof(double)*OutN, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printf("welcome31\n");

    cudaMalloc((void **)&alpha_p_GPU, sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(alpha_p_GPU, &alpha, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&beta_p_GPU, sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(beta_p_GPU, &beta, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&sumtemp_p_GPU, sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(sumtemp_p_GPU, &sumtemp, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&errtemp_p_GPU, sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(errtemp_p_GPU, &errtemp, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&w_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*InputN*hn);
    cudaMemcpy(w_p_GPU, &w, sizeof(double)*(InputN*hn), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&v_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*hn*OutN);
    cudaMemcpy(v_p_GPU, &v, sizeof(double)*(hn*OutN), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&deltaw_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*InputN*hn);
    cudaMemcpy(deltaw_p_GPU, &deltaw, sizeof(double)*(InputN*hn), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&deltav_p_GPU, sizeof(double)*hn*OutN);
    cudaMemcpy(deltav_p_GPU, &deltav, sizeof(double)*(hn*OutN), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

printf("welcome40\n");

    launch(randData, times_p_GPU, loop_p_GPU, error_p_GPU, max_p_GPU, min_p_GPU, x_out_p_GPU, hn_out_p_GPU, y_out_p_GPU, y_p_GPU, w_p_GPU, v_p_GPU, deltaw_p_GPU, deltav_p_GPU, hn_delta_p_GPU, y_delta_p_GPU, alpha_p_GPU, beta_p_GPU, sumtemp_p_GPU, errtemp_p_GPU);

printf("welcome41\n");

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
printf("welcome_after_kernel\n");
}
```

`file.cu` :

```
#define w(i,j) w[(i)*(InputN*hn) + (j)]
#define v(i,j) v[(i)*(hn*OutN) + (j)]
#define x_out(i,j) x_out[(i)*(InputN) + (j)]
#define y(i,j) y[(i)*(OutN) + (j)]
#define hn_out(i,j) hn_out[(i)*(hn) + (j)]
#define y_out(i,j) y_out[(i)*(OutN) + (j)]
#define y_delta(i,j) y_delta[(i)*(OutN) + (j)]
#define hn_delta(i,j) hn_delta[(i)*(hn) + (j)]
#define deltav(i,j) deltav[(i)*(hn*OutN) + (j)]
#define deltaw(i,j) deltaw[(i)*(InputN*hn) + (j)]

#define datanum 4       // number of training samples
#define InputN 16       // number of neurons in the input layer
#define hn 64           // number of neurons in the hidden layer
#define OutN 1          // number of neurons in the output layer
#define threads_per_block 256
#define MAX_RAND 100
#define MIN_RAND 10

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>   //for truncf()


// sigmoid serves as avtivation function
__device__ double sigmoid(double x){
    return(1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x)));
}


__device__ int rand_kernel(int index, float *randData){
    float myrandf = randData[index];
    myrandf *= (MAX_RAND - MIN_RAND + 0.999999);
    myrandf += MIN_RAND;
    int myrand = (int)truncf(myrandf);
    return myrand;
}


__global__ void neural_network_kernel (float *randData, int *times, int *loop, double *error, double *max, double *min, double *x_out, double *hn_out, double *y_out, double *y, double *w, double *v, double *deltaw, double *deltav, double *hn_delta, double *y_delta, double *alpha, double *beta, double *sumtemp, double *errtemp)
{
    //int i = blockIdx.x;
    //int idx = threadIdx.x;
    //int idy = threadIdx.y

    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    // training set
    struct{
        double input_kernel[InputN];
        double teach_kernel[OutN];
    }data_kernel[threads_per_block + datanum];

    if (index==0)
    {
        for(int m=0; m<datanum; m++){
            for(int i=0; i<InputN; i++)
                data_kernel[threads_per_block + m].input_kernel[i] = (double)rand_kernel(index, randData)/32767.0;
            for(int i=0;i<OutN;i++)
                data_kernel[threads_per_block + m].teach_kernel[i] = (double)rand_kernel(index, randData)/32767.0;
        }
    }


    // Initialization
    for(int i=0; i<InputN; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<hn; j++){
            w(i,j) = ((double)rand_kernel(index, randData)/32767.0)*2-1;
            deltaw(i,j) = 0;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<hn; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<OutN; j++){
            v(i,j) = ((double)rand_kernel(index, randData)/32767.0)*2-1;
            deltav(i,j) = 0;
        }
    }


    while(loop[index] < *times){
        loop[index]++;
        error[index] = 0.0;

        for(int m=0; m<datanum ; m++){
            // Feedforward
            max[index] = 0.0;
            min[index] = 0.0;
            for(int i=0; i<InputN; i++){
                x_out(index,i) = data_kernel[threads_per_block + m].input_kernel[i];
                if(max[index] < x_out(index,i))
                    max[index] = x_out(index,i);
                if(min[index] > x_out(index,i))
                    min[index] = x_out(index,i);
            }
            for(int i=0; i<InputN; i++){
                x_out(index,i) = (x_out(index,i) - min[index]) / (max[index] - min[index]);
            }

            for(int i=0; i<OutN ; i++){
                y(index,i) = data_kernel[threads_per_block + m].teach_kernel[i];
            }

            for(int i=0; i<hn; i++){
                sumtemp[index] = 0.0;
                for(int j=0; j<InputN; j++)
                    sumtemp[index] += w(j,i) * x_out(index,j);
                hn_out(index,i) = sigmoid(sumtemp[index]);      // sigmoid serves as the activation function
            }

            for(int i=0; i<OutN; i++){
                sumtemp[index] = 0.0;
                for(int j=0; j<hn; j++)
                    sumtemp[index] += v(j,i) * hn_out(index,j);
                y_out(index,i) = sigmoid(sumtemp[index]);
            }

            // Backpropagation
            for(int i=0; i<OutN; i++){
                errtemp[index] = y(index,i) - y_out(index,i);
                y_delta(index,i) = -errtemp[index] * sigmoid(y_out(index,i)) * (1.0 - sigmoid(y_out(index,i)));
                error[index] += errtemp[index] * errtemp[index];
            }

            for(int i=0; i<hn; i++){
                errtemp[index] = 0.0;
                for(int j=0; j<OutN; j++)
                    errtemp[index] += y_delta(index,j) * v(i,j);
                hn_delta(index,i) = errtemp[index] * (1.0 + hn_out(index,i)) * (1.0 - hn_out(index,i));
            }

            // Stochastic gradient descent
            for(int i=0; i<OutN; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<hn; j++){
                    deltav(j,i) = (*alpha) * deltav(j,i) + (*beta) * y_delta(index,i) * hn_out(index,j);
                    v(j,i) -= deltav(j,i);
                }
            }

            for(int i=0; i<hn; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<InputN; j++){
                    deltaw(j,i) = (*alpha) * deltaw(j,i) + (*beta) * hn_delta(index,i) * x_out(index,j);
                    w(j,i) -= deltaw(j,i);
                }
            }
        }

        // Global error
        error[index] = error[index] / 2;
        /*if(loop%1000==0){
            result = "Global Error = ";
            sprintf(buffer, "%f", error);
            result += buffer;
            result += "\r\n";
        }
        if(error < errlimit)
            break;*/

        printf("The %d th training, error: %0.100f\n", loop[index], error[index]);
    }
}


extern "C"
void launch(float *randData, int *times, int *loop, double *error, double *max, double *min, double *x_out, double *hn_out, double *y_out, double *y, double *w, double *v, double *deltaw, double *deltav, double *hn_delta, double *y_delta, double *alpha, double *beta, double *sumtemp, double *errtemp)
{
    int blocks = *times/threads_per_block;
    neural_network_kernel<<<blocks, threads_per_block>>>(randData, times, loop, error, max, min, x_out, hn_out, y_out, y, w, v, deltaw, deltav, hn_delta, y_delta, alpha, beta, sumtemp, errtemp);
}
```

UPDATE :

I found some mistakes about memory allocation with the pointers. I updated the code above... Now the major issues are:

1) Is the link/compilation correctly made, is this how I should do it? I mean with the first way.

2) I found out that the blinking cursor is shown immediately during the first `cudaMalloc()`. Until that point it runs correctly.

But at first `cudaMalloc()` it hangs forever, why?

Answer (score 1):

Before asking for help here, its good practice to use proper cuda error checking and run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.  If you don't, you may be ignoring useful error information and wasting your time as well as others trying to help you.

> In the second case, since the -l parameters are not recognized (only -lcuda is), I guess because I didn't specify their paths since I don't know where these files are stored.

You don't want to skip these.  `nvcc` will automatically link against some of these libraries for you, and automatically knows where to find them.  When using g++, you have to tell it where to look and the specific libraries you need.  For the code you have shown, you don't need all those libraries you are linking against, so the following should be sufficient:

```
   g++ -o program file1.o file2.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
```

for a standard linux install of CUDA.  If you don't have a standard install, you can do `which nvcc` to find out the location of `nvcc`, and then use that to find the likely place where the libraries are located (change the `bin` in the path to `lib64`)

If you actually need some of those other libraries, things like `cutil` and `cudpp` won't be available unless you go to special steps to install them, and you will need to identify the path to them in that case.

Regarding `cuPrintf`, if you are compiling and running on a cc2.0 or newer GPU (which is teh lowest compute capability that is supported by CUDA 8 anyway), you should not need that.  ordinary `printf` should work in device code, and if it is not (because you have a device code error - use proper error checking and `cuda-memcheck`) then `cuPrintf` won't work any better.  So rather than wrestling with getting that working, just revert the code to use `printf` instead (and include `stdio.h`).

Regarding your program and why it is not working, I think you probably have a number of errors.  You may want to learn how to use a debugger.  Right of the bat, in host code, your attempt to initialize `randData` from host code is illegal.

Now that I see you have changed the question several times now, turning it into a moving target, I will stop.

Stop with the moving target if you want help.

Use proper cuda error checking.