# Compiling CUDA sample program

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, linker, cublas

I have a very simple CUDA program that refuses to compile

This is `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h"
#include "/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cublas_v2.h"

// Function to initialize a matrix with random values
void initMatrix(float* matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;  // Initialize with random values
    }
}

// Function to print a matrix
void printMatrix(float* matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            std::cout << matrix[i * cols + j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    // Matrix dimensions
    int m = 3;  // Number of rows
    int n = 3;  // Number of columns

    // Allocate host memory for the matrix and vector
    float* h_matrix = new float[m * n];
    float* h_vector = new float[n];

    // Initialize matrix and vector with random values
    initMatrix(h_matrix, m, n);
    initMatrix(h_vector, n, 1);

    // Print the matrix and vector
    std::cout << "Matrix:" << std::endl;
    printMatrix(h_matrix, m, n);

    std::cout << "\nVector:" << std::endl;
    printMatrix(h_vector, n, 1);

    // Allocate device memory for the matrix and vector
    float* d_matrix;
    float* d_vector;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_matrix, m * n * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_vector, n * sizeof(float));

    // Transfer the matrix and vector from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_matrix, h_matrix, m * n * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_vector, h_vector, n * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // cuBLAS handle
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);

    // Perform matrix-vector multiplication
    float alpha = 1.0;  // Scaling factor
    float beta = 0.0;   // Scaling factor
    cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, n, &alpha, d_matrix, m, d_vector, 1, &beta, d_vector, 1);

    // Transfer the result back to the host
    cudaMemcpy(h_vector, d_vector, m * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Print the result
    std::cout << "\nResult:" << std::endl;
    printMatrix(h_vector, m, 1);

    // Clean up
    delete[] h_matrix;
    delete[] h_vector;
    cudaFree(d_matrix);
    cudaFree(d_vector);
    cublasDestroy(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

This is `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(CUBLAS_Matrix_Vector_Multiplication LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF)
add_definitions(-std=c++11)

set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

add_executable(matrix_vector_multiplication main.cpp)

target_include_directories(matrix_vector_multiplication PRIVATE ${CUDAToolkit_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set_target_properties(matrix_vector_multiplication PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON CUDA_STANDARD 11)
target_link_libraries(matrix_vector_multiplication PRIVATE ${CUDAToolkit_LIBRARIES})
```

trying to compile it by `cmake` create the config files. But then `make` causes a lot of errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/matrix_vector_multiplication.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x8056): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x8072): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x8098): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x80ba): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x80c6): undefined reference to `cublasCreate_v2'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x8112): undefined reference to `cublasSgemv_v2'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x8138): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x81c6): undefined reference to `cudaFree'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x81d2): undefined reference to `cudaFree'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x81de): undefined reference to `cublasDestroy_v2'
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/matrix_vector_multiplication.dir/build.make:97: matrix_vector_multiplication] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/matrix_vector_multiplication.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Fehler 2
```

**Attempt to Resolve**

I tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498885/cuda-and-c-link-compilation-program-crashes-on-cudamalloc), and used:

```
 g++ main.cpp -o main -L/opt/cuda/lib64/ -lcudart -lcuda -L/opt/cuda
```

This throws the error:

```
In file included from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cublas_v2.h:69,
                 from main.cpp:4:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cublas_api.h:77:10: fatal error: cuda_fp16.h: No such file or directory
   77 | #include <cuda_fp16.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How can I resolve the issue?

```
 nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__8_19:17:24_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.3, V12.3.52
Build cuda_12.3.r12.3/compiler.33281558_0
```

Comment: add `-I/opt/cuda/include` towards the beginning and `-lcublas`  towards the end of your `g++` command line.  And `-L/opt/cuda` should not be necessary.

Comment: OOO thank you. 
this seem to work. I will modify the CMakeLists as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the includes to

```cpp
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
```

this should work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(CUBLAS_Matrix_Vector_Multiplication LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)

add_executable(matrix_vector_multiplication main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(matrix_vector_multiplication
    PRIVATE
        CUDA::cublas
        CUDA::cudart
)
target_compile_features(matrix_vector_multiplication
    PRIVATE
        cxx_std_11
)
```

The `CUDA` language in CMake and many options that you are trying to use are only needed for compiling code written in the CUDA C++ dialect, i.e. custom kernels. Other than that I used the cleanest/modernest way of specifying the C++ standard version. With the `CUDA::` targets, CMake will take care of specifying the right include paths to the compiler with `-I` such that the hard-coded paths you used are not needed anymore (I **had to** change them for testing the `CMakeLists.txt` as the paths are different on my system). It will also take care of any dependencies of these targets.

For more information on the targets made available, see [`FindCUDAToolkit`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html).